# Need an optimization algorithm

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I need this algorithm for one of my projects. I will paraphrase the problem.

There are 'n' ropes that have different colored rings on them. (The colors might repeat on the same rope or across different ropes).

My job is to pick a few of these ropes and join them such that all the colors in the n ropes are included in that joined rope. I should get the smallest rope size possible.
I am allowed to cut each rope once and discard the end part if needed.

It will be nice to have exact solution for this.(This gives us something like a goal that our project is aiming to achieve). Can someone tell me how I might approach this? The n is about 10^5 for my work.

Comment: How many rings are there on each rope? How many colors are there? What could you possibly gain by cutting off a tail of the rope, presumably you'd cut off colors that are already in the head; if so, why "ropes" and not just "sets of colors"?

Comment: @vonbrand I expanded on the question here: please check it out, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/227732/118622